# what happens with Schedule job and other processes during salesforce maintenance

Tags: apex, visualforce, scheduled-apex

Many times maintenance window is shown when we login in salesforce. My question is when this maintenance is going on at that particular time what happens with the schedule jobs, apex jobs and other processes of different applications .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no impact on the scheduled jobs, batch, scheduled, long-running transactions, or bulk API jobs prior to the maintenance. Salesforce will queue all jobs and process them once the maintenance is complete.

You can find more detailed explanation in this link:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-is-my-org-impacted-during-Salesforce-maintenance&language=en_US

Answer (score 3):

In context of Test cases and deployment

- Salesforce saves the results of executed tests in chunks. Therefore,
  a small portion of tests might not have their results saved because
  they weren’t part of the last saved chunk. These tests are rerun when
  the deployment is restarted.
- If the deployment interruption happens before tests have started, the
  entire deployment restarts from the beginning.